# Lanzar automáticamente un programa en python cuando se cierra por fallo

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, bash

Tengo un programa en Python 2.7 corriendo en Ubuntu16. Este programa está diseñado para trabajar durante meses en segundo plano capturando tweets. El problema es que cada semana aproximadamente, aparece un error en una de las librerías y el programa deja de funcionar sin previo aviso.

Necesito una solución que vuelva a lanzar el programa python en cuanto se produzca un bloqueo y se cierre. ¿Alguien tiene una solución? Gracias

Comment: Por que no haces un segundo programa que detecte si esta corriendo el primero. y si no lo ejecute. puedes hacerlo vigilando los procesos en ejecución o consultando el estado del servicio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primero de todo, si el script termina  mediante una excepción que puedes capturar, **lo normal es que manejes dicha excepción para que el propio proceso se autogestione** y cuando ocurra el fallo vuelva a inicializar todo lo que sea necesario para poder continuar.

Python permite un gran manejo de las excepciones, si sabes de antemano que se puede producir una excepción que no está en tus manos corregir, en vez de dejar que tu proceso termine de forma abrupta es mejor capturar dicha excepción y terminar de forma controlada el trabajo que esté haciendo (o reiniciarlo) llevando a cabo el proceso de forma segura (cierre de archivos o sockets abiertos, terminación controlada de hilos, etc).

Un ejemplo muy simplificado para ilustrar a que me refiero es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

def main():
    time.sleep(10)
    raise RuntimeError()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            main()

        except RuntimeError:
            print("[WARNING]: script execution fail.")
            continue

        break
```

Si durante la ejecución de `main()` se produce una excepción de tipo `RuntimeError` (en este caso siempre se produce a los 10 segundos de ser llamada) se vuelve a llamar de nuevo repitiendo el proceso indefinidamente. Si termina de forma adecuada o a causa de otra excepción (p.e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) el proceso termina.

En caso de no ser posible lo anterior  tienes varias opciones:

- **Usar el gestor de demonios [Systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):** si mal no recuerdo 
  desde 15.04 está integrado en el sistema. Además de permitirte inicializar el servicio manualmente y que se reinicie en caso de fallo de forma automática, puedes hacer que este se inicie al arranque del sistema. La idea básica es crear un nuevo fichero .service:

  ```
  $ sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/twitterBot.service
  $ sudo chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/twitterBot.service
  $ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/twitterBot.service
  ```

  El contenido del fichero básico puede ser:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=Python Twitter monitor
  After=network.target
  After=systemd-user-sessions.service
  After=network-online.target

  [Service]  
  ExecStart=/ruta/a/tu/script.py
  Restart=on-failure

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

  Editado el *.service* lo guardamos y recargamos:

  ```
  $ systemctl daemon-reload
  ```

  Con esto podemos iniciar nuestro servicio cuando queramos con:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl start twitterBot
  ```

  Deternerlo con:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl stop twitterBot
  ```

  Habilitarlo para ser ejecutado en el arranque del sistema:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl enable twitterBot.service
  ```

  Deshabilitarlo para ser ejecutado en el arranque del sistema:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl disable twitterBot.service
  ```

  Obtener información del servicio:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl status twitterBot.service
  ```

  Esto es solo un ejemplo básico, systemd tiene mucho más potencial, en el enlace anterior tienes la documentación.

  > **Importante:** No olvidar dar permisos de ejecución al script y asegurarse de tener la linea de shebang apropiada al inicio del mismo que apunte al intérprete correcto (p.e `#!/usr/bin/env python2`).
- **Usar `cron`** para programar una tarea que cada x tiempo compruebe si el proceso continua en ejecución y que en caso contrario lo relance.
- **Usar un segundo script** en Python o bash que sea el encargado de lanzar el subproceso y de lanzarlo de nuevo si este no termina de forma esperada. La idea básica sería algo así:

  ```
  import subprocess

  path = "ruta/a/tu/script.py"

  while True:
      try:
          subprocess.check_call(["python2", path])
      except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
          continue
  ```

Seguramente existen muchas más ideas, como la que comenta @Gytree, usando un script en vez de cron que compruebe si el proceso está está en funcionamiento cada x tiempo. No obstante, en mi opinión, lo primero es hacer que el script autogestione sus excepciones (en vez de terminar abruptamente cuando esta se produzca) y para todo lo demás (por ejemplo, el proceso termina por apagado inesperado del equipo) Systemd es una herramienta muy buena.

Comment: Gran respuesta, FJSevilla. Se te coló un `def main():de forma controlada` por allí.

Comment: Gracias por el aviso @fedorqui, se me ha escapado el mismo dos veces además... He corregido este y otro typo que había por falta de un `]` de cierre. Espero que no queden más... He publicado desde una tablet y soy propenso a meter la pata y mucho al publicar con dispositivos móviles (y no hablemos si hay un corrector de por medio) XD.

Comment: Jajaja, cuando publico desde móvil me pasa lo mismo, es una locura. Dicho lo cual, qué daría yo por publicar desde un ordenador de sobremesa respuestas tan potentes como las que tú publicas desde tablet ;-D

Comment: @FJSevilla una respuesta espectacular. El error que me arroja python es el siguiente:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./programa.py", line 64, in <module>
    myStream.filter(languages=['es'], track=[param])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: Por lo tanto, he añadido la excepción: `except AttributeError:` y dentro de unos días (o semanas) podré confirmar que tal ha ido. ¡Pero por ahora tiene muy buena pinta! Gracias.