# ¿Cómo se hace en linux para ejecutar un archivo python al arrancar la máquina?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

Quería saber cómo se hace para que Linux inicie una ejecución de una programa python al arrancar la máquina. Para entender un poco la necesidad, es un programa (en python) domótico que he creado con Raspberry, pero si se va la luz por cualquier motivo y vuelve, se enciende la máquina Raspberry pero claro, el archivo python no se ejecuta. ¡Y me quedo sin luz en casa! xD

La aplicación es esta siguiente que se guarda en "domotica.py" y quiero que al encenderse la raspberry ejecute domotica.py automáticamente.

Simplemente hace scraping de una web donde se alojan el estado de cada habitáculo de casa 1 = encedido / 0 = apagado. Que mediante una web con unos botones que hace update se modifica la base de datos, y también la web que muestra el estado de cada habitación de casa. Raspberry hace scrapping y si ve 1 el relé enciende la luz, y si ve 0 lo apaga.

Código de scrapping y control de relés:

```
 #coding: utf-8
def ejecutarScript():
    #coding: utf-8
    import time
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
    print("retegi system")
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    page = requests.get("http://...")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    #LUZSALON 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzSalon"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Salón ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Salón ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)

    #LUZHABITACION 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzHabitacion"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Habitación ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Habitación ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)

    #LUZCOCINA 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzCocina"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Cocina ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(5, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Cocina ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(5, GPIO.HIGH)

    #LUZENTRADA 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzEntrada"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Entrada ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Entrada ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)

    #LUZCALLE 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzCalle"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Calle ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Calle ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)  

    #LUZARMARIO 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzArmario"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Armario ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Armario ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)

    #LUZARMARIO 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzCuartoLavado"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Cuarto Lavado ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(19, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Cuarto Lavado ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(19, GPIO.HIGH)  

    #LUZARMARIO 1 ó 0
    for tweet in soup.find_all(class_="luzDespensa"):
        luzSalon = (tweet.get_text())
    if(luzSalon == "1"):
        print ("luz Despensa ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print ("luz Despensa ")
        print luzSalon
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)  


    time.sleep(5)
while True:
    ejecutarScript()
```

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: podrías poner algo extra, como por ejemplo el comando que usas para correrlo? Algún dato de las versiones que usas? etc

Comment: ¿Así mejor? : ) No es necesario el código para la solución que busco, pero si alguien lo quiere mirar incluso mejorarlo, bienvenido sea, ya que soy nuevo en python y scrapping... Por cierto, los relés funcionan y todo eso. ; )

Comment: Podrías usar [Systemd](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md), mírate esta respuesta mía a otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/148407/15089 dónde hablo de esto.

Comment: Hola talvez te sirva https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46125       https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4123/running-a-python-script-at-startup

Comment: Lo he hecho al final siguiente este videotutorial que utiliza el bash.bashrc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJbKvEWZXak Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No se si esto pueda solucionar tu problema:

Necesitas crear un archivo bash que indique la ruta y por ende el archivo que deseas que inicie por ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Desktop
python ejecutable.py
```

Y una vez hecho esto en la linea de comandos debemos abrir el crontab(sudo crontab -e)

y añades lo siguiente:

```
@reboot /home/pi/Desktop/auto-ejecutador.sh
```

Guardamos y ya debería estar listo

Answer (score 1):

El archivo `/etc/rc.local` se ejecuta al final del proceso de arranque del equipo.

Agrega `python tu_script.py` a `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar cron, que permite programar tareas, indicando que la tarea se ejecute al arranque del sistema con el flag @reboot

Si añades a la cabecera del script un shebang, podrás hacer que ese script se ejecute desde python.

En tu caso, el shebang sería:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

También debes darles permisos de ejecución, con

```
chmod o+x domotica.py
```

Con esto ya cron podrá ejecutar el script.

Y, finalmente, para añadir la tarea cron, ejecutas:

```
crontab -e
```

Esto te abrirá un editor, en el que debes añadir la tarea.

```
@reboot [ruta_al_script]
```

Si la ruta fuera, por ejemplo, `/opt/domotica.py`, la tarea quedaría como:

```
@reboot /opt/domotica.py
```

Una vez copiada esa linea en el editor de `crontab -e`, guardas los cambios y cierras. Y con esto, ya la tarea cron queda programa, y tu script se ejecutará en el arranque del sistema