# ¿Como reiniciar un programa python en raspberry automaticamente?

Tags: python

Muy buenas tengan todos, tengo un programa python ejecutándose en raspberry pi 3 que utiliza request para comunicarse con un script web y quiero saber si en caso de que el programa en raspberry se cuelgue, hay forma de saber si se cuelga y si se puede volver a ejecutar el programa automáticamente sin supervisor del usuario

Comment: Hola Jo3krJP, bienvenid@ a [es.so]. Mírate el gestor de demonios  [Systemd](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md), si por "cuelgue" te refieres a una terminación no controlada del proceso es posiblemente la mejor opción en el caso de no poder gestionar la excepción adecuadamente desde  el propio script. Posible duplicado de [Lanzar automáticamente un programa en python cuando se cierra por fallo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/148351/15089)

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría que el script que quieres monitorizar escribiera un fichero a modo de heartbeat. 
Tienes que tener otro script en el cron que mire si existe el fichero de heartbeat, si es así entonces borra el fichero, si no existiera, le dejas un par de ciclos por si acaso y si sigue sin tener heartbeat, entonces matas el proceso y lo relanzas.

El segundo script, el que monitoriza tiene que ser lo mas sencillo posible para que ese no pueda cascar.

Mira también en el fichero /etc/inittab, ahí es donde se meten los demonios que quieres que el SO esté pendiente, si se mueren o los matas, se relanzan solos.

Comment: Gracias muchas gracias intentare las sugerencias que me das